# Excel, VBA, Textbox: Sort text parts based on their ID numbers?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I'pretty new to the page and also Excel vba codes. So I run into a problem at work and I would be happy for some help.
I have the following problem. In my UserForm9 I have a lot of textboxes for entering data to Excel cells. In the form is one textbox where QR code data gets scanned into. The code format is “P1000 3214”, “P1220 3101”, and so on. It is always Pxxxx_xxxx.

[image: Printscreen of Userform]

What I am trying to do is the following:
When QR code gets scanned into textbox1 copy the LAST 4 numbers AUTOMATICALY into another textbox associated with the "P and the FIRST 4 numbers (P1000). The "P" and first 4 numbers are an identifier for Ingredients in my case and should be linked to textboxes (example: P1000 linked to Textbox2 and Textbox3 (If textbox2 is already full).

I have about 30 such indentifiers (P1000, P1500) so i do not know if that can be written in one universal code or if it needs to be written for each identifier again and again.

I can not find an answer with Google, so you are my last chance to get that problem fixed.

Thanks a lot if any of you can help me.

Simon

Comment: Make bindings between the 4 digit numbers (on the left of the form) to the textboxes name in the same row. Are they Labels? Or they must be generated dinamically when reading the QR code? Or do that 9 numbers are permanent?

Comment: Hello BC. Thanks for yor comment. :) The 4 digits on the left side are just plain text, for easier user orientation. They are NOT generated dinamicaly and are permanent. The Userform is part of an food recipe so it will change in other food recipe workbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be better solutions than this if you named your TextBoxes after the 'P' codes, but assuming they are named 'Tb1', 'Tb2' etc, then try this ... the code must go in the code-behind of the UserForm. The code commented for your understanding.

```
Private Sub Tb1_Change()
    Dim sText As String
    sText = UCase(Tb1.Text) ' in case of lowercase 'p' ... if required?
    ' validate contents of the TextBox are as expected
    If Len(sText) = 10 Then
        If Mid$(sText, 1, 1) = "P" And Mid$(sText, 6, 1) = " " Then
            ' split the text into the two parts (before and after the space)
            Dim sTextBeforeSpace As String, sTextAfterSpace As String
            sTextBeforeSpace = Left$(sText, 5)
            sTextAfterSpace = Right$(sText, 4)
            ' update the other TextBoxes based on the text in the first part (before the space)
            Select Case sTextBeforeSpace
                Case "P1000": UpdateTextBoxesWithCodes sTextAfterSpace, Tb2, Tb3
                Case "P1018": UpdateTextBoxesWithCodes sTextAfterSpace, Tb4, Tb5
                ' ... add other Case statements as required, adjusting the 'P' code and the names of the TextBoxes
            End Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub UpdateTextBoxesWithCodes(sTextAfterSpace As String, tbLeft As MSForms.TextBox, tbRight As MSForms.TextBox)
    ' if the left TextBox (eg Tb2) is empty then put the text into it, otherwise
    'into the right TextBox (eg Tb3)
    If Len(tbLeft.Text) = 0 Then
        tbLeft.Text = sTextAfterSpace
    Else
        tbRight.Text = sTextAfterSpace
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use tag property of your textboxes
give for example Tb2 value of P1000_0 and Tb3 P1000_1(if P1000_0 has value)

with a loop check the tag value of textboxes and put value in the right one

for example

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim nextCtrl As msforms.TextBox
Set nextCtrl = Nothing


Dim value1 As String
value1 = "P1000 3122" 'value of qr code
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls 'for all controls in userform
    If TypeOf ctrl Is msforms.TextBox Then 'if the control is a textbox then
        If UCase(ctrl.Tag) = UCase(Left(value1, 5)) & "_0" Then 'if control has the tag P1000_0 then
            If Trim(ctrl.Text) = "" Then ctrl.Text = Right(value1, 4): Exit Sub 'if control is empty enter value and exit sub
        End If
        If UCase(ctrl.Tag) = UCase(Left(value1, 5)) & "_1" Then Set nextCtrl = ctrl 'if control is P1000_1 then store it in nextCtrl
    End If
Next

If nextCtrl Is Nothing Then 'if no value then exit
    Exit Sub
Else 'if there is value it means that P1000_0 was not empty so
    nextCtrl.Text = Right(value1, 4) 'give P1000_1 textbox  value
End If
End Sub
```